# Like Box with Recommendations feed

Tags: recommendation-engine, facebook-likebox

I want to use the like box or something to show the Recommendations given on my pages timeline. It shows comments on the wall as such but there appears to be no plugin to show any 'Recommendations' which is specifically prompted on the timeline.  I looked at the recommendations box but that doesn't so what I would have imagined in this context